Unable to access Rest endpoints even after successful login in spring security through react form
I am trying to implement login authentication in spring boot ,I have used Spring security and used a react form in the frontend to authenticate , I am using axios to call my /login which works well, the form opens and authenticates perfectly but the problem lies here is that after login is successful i am unable to access other endpoints declared in my spring controller
This is my Spring security config
   @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->auth
                        .requestMatchers("/","/login/**","/register")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .logout(logout->logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session->session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED))
                .build();
    }


My login controller
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody RegisterUser registerUser) {
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(registerUser.getEmail(), registerUser.getPassword())
            );
            if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Login successful");
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Login failed");
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Login failed");
        }
        
    }

This is my react form
axios.defaults.baseURL="http://localhost:8080"
axios.defaults.withCredentials=true;

const Login=()=>{
    const [email, setEmail]=React.useState('');
    const [password, setpassword]=React.useState('');
    const [error, setError] = React.useState('');
    const navigate =useNavigate();

    const handlesubmit= async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("/login" ,{
                email,
                password,
            });

            if(response.status===200){
                console.error(email,password)
                navigate('/');
            }
            else {
                navigate('/logs')
            }
        }
        catch (e){
            console.error(e)
            setError("login failed")
        }
    }

Tried using login->login.form("/login") and loginprocesssurl("/login") in security config yet doesnt work, I have also set my proxy to the port where spring is running yet i have no results
What i want now is after the login is successful ( it is ) i want to access the other endpoints which only authenticated users can access

Unable to access is not a helpful description. What exact error or symptoms are you seeing?

@aled unable to access in the sense even after sucessfull login when i hit the endpoint /mydata i get 404

With the custom endpoint, there is one slight detail missing: SecurityContext is not populated during the login request/response. Without storing it, further requests still will be anonymous despite successful authentication.
Preferred way is having login logic in the SecurityFilterChain:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(...)
            .formLogin(it -> it
                .loginPage("/") // mapped to index.html, letting react handle it
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                    response.getWriter().print("Login successful");
                })
                .failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
                    response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Login failed");
                })
            )
            .logout(...)
            ...
            .build();
}

Why's that? It adds additional UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, which contains the authentication logic of your @PostMapping("/login") endpoint + it stores the SecurityContext in ThreadLocal. Later it is saved by SecurityContextRepository in the other filter down the chain. (Note, it requires explicit save since 6 version)
If you really want to control the signing in flow in your endpoint (maybe for some side effects), save the context there:
...
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody RegisterUser registerUser) {
try {
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(registerUser.getEmail(), registerUser.getPassword())
            );
            if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {

                // storing context in ThreadLocal, later will be saved in SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
                SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                context.setAuthentication(authentication);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

                return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Login successful");
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Login failed");
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Login failed");
        }
        
    }
...


Hi, I tried out your code yet it still doesn't  seem to work , when i added the form login in security filter chain the form authentication fails and redirect me even if the login details are wrong but even so i am unable to access the other endpoints , it gives me 404

Could you tell, please, what's the version of Spring Security? Yes, it redirects even in case of failure because you check it for response.status===200 in your react form (while having 403 status in response). Are your other URLs correct? No prefix like '/api'? I'm asking as you get 404, not 403 or 200. Will 404 still be present if you .anyRequest().permitAll()?

Hi, when i did anyrequest().permitall() i did get access to other API endpoint , thanks but I figured out a own solution , what I did was i allowed spring security to allow/permit all api access but now that the protected endpoints are not secure I implemented JWT in the react side , when login is successfully from the spring side , i set a JWT in my react local storage and authenticate and secure and protect all the API , works like charm , idk wheather its a good practice but it works!

it is not, because having JWTs in the browser is not recommended, you cant logout users. But good luck
